# UIImageView crash when trying to set the frame

Tags: ios4, uiview, uiimageview

First here's my crash log:

> Thread 0 Crashed:
>   0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x35176264 __kill + 8
>   1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x35176254 kill + 4
>   2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x35176246 raise + 10
>   3   libSystem.B.dylib               0x3518ad02 abort + 50
>   4   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x31432a20 __gnu_cxx::__verbose_terminate_handler() + 376
>   5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x31a97594 _objc_terminate + 104
>   6   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x31430df2 _*cxxabiv1::*_terminate(void (*)()) + 46
>   7   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x31430e46 std::terminate() + 10
>   8   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x31430f16 __cxa_throw + 78
>   9   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x31a964c4 objc_exception_throw + 64
>   10  CoreFoundation                  0x361857c2 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 62
>   11  CoreFoundation                  0x361857fc +[NSException raise:format:] + 28
>   12  QuartzCore                      0x3148b222 CALayerSetPosition(CALayer*, CA::Vec2 const&, bool) + 134
>   13  QuartzCore                      0x3148b190 -[CALayer setPosition:] + 32
>   14  QuartzCore                      0x3148b0dc -[CALayer setFrame:] + 384
>   15  UIKit                           0x35d15aba -[UIView(Geometry) setFrame:] + 182
>   16  UIKit                           0x35d15928 -[UIImageView setFrame:] + 96

I have copied a part from the crash log. After line 16 there are my classes, which I cannot present here. In MyClass and MyMethod I change the frame of an imageView. My problem is that I cannot reproduce this bug and I want to reproduce it. What causes this log? I tried to release the imageView before I call the setFrame:, but it doesn't produce this error.
Any ideas how to get it?  Or why this error happens some times?

Comment: It's kind of hard to tell without seeing any code. However, if it's not reproducible I'd say it's probably a memory issue. Check if you've managed all retain counts correctly. It might also be useful to test the app for leaks with instruments.

Comment: If you're unable to reproduce your code, as you say, then it's going to be difficult to help you resolve your issue with anything more than a crash log. Start with examining how you are setting the frame of the `UIImageView` and work backwards from there.

Comment: That's bad, because I tried to force the deallocating of the imageView, the app crashes at setFrame: , but not with this log. Why is it present the [NSException raise:format:] in this log? Do you guys have any idea?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I recognize this problem from one of my own projects. Usually when `setFrame:` crashes it's because your trying to set a NaN (Not a number). I don't know if you've dealt with NaN before, but if you haven't drop a comment and I'll provide information on how to deal with it.

**EDIT:** Had some time and thought I might give you an example.

So here's a code example to explain why the bug is hard to reproduce and how to fix it. I don't know what your code looks like, but your problem sounds similar enough to make me believe that you've done the same mistake as I did.

Consider the following code:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
    CGRect imageFrame;
    switch (self.state) {
        case 0:
            imageFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100);
        case 1:
            imageFrame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 50, 50);
    }
    self.imageView.frame = imageFrame;
}
```

Consider that `self.state` is 2, then `imageFrame` will never be initialized and will contain whatever was on that memory location, possibly NaN. The reason why this is hard to reproduce is that the crash will only occur when there is NaN on that memory location.

In my example the error is very easy to spot and it's likely that it's not as easy to spot in your code. If you can't find it yourself, feel free to post your code and I'll take a look at it. If you have any questions, don't hesitate to leave a comment.